# Azure Linux based .NET core 3.0 deployment on App service Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.UIFrameworkAttribute'

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, .net-core-3.0, kudu

I'm trying to deploy a simple .NETCORE 3.0 project to app service without using docker.

Note that the project is using individual authentication

[image: individual authentication]

The project is working well in visual studio and if I bundled it in a docker container as well.

When I try to use the web app service Deployment Center and connect it to the git repo directly using Kudu the I got this issue.

> Running the command: dotnet "WebApplication1.dll"
>   Unhandled exception. System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.UIFrameworkAttribute' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
>   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
>   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(MetadataToken caCtorToken, MetadataImport& scope, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, ListBuilder`1& derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg)
>   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.AddCustomAttributes(ListBuilder`1& attributes, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, ListBuilder`1 derivedAttributes)
>   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType)
>   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeAssembly assembly, RuntimeType caType)
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
>   at System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(Assembly element, Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
>   at System.Reflection.CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttributes[T](Assembly element)
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartManager.GetApplicationPartAssemblies(String entryAssemblyName)
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartManager.PopulateDefaultParts(String entryAssemblyName)
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcCoreServiceCollectionExtensions.GetApplicationPartManager(IServiceCollection services)
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcCoreServiceCollectionExtensions.AddMvcCore(IServiceCollection services)
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.AddControllersCore(IServiceCollection services)
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.AddControllersWithViewsCore(IServiceCollection services)
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.AddControllersWithViews(IServiceCollection services)
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.AddMvc(IServiceCollection services)
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityBuilderUIExtensions.AddRelatedParts(IdentityBuilder builder, UIFramework framework)
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityBuilderUIExtensions.AddDefaultUI(IdentityBuilder builder, UIFramework framework)
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityBuilderUIExtensions.AddDefaultUI(IdentityBuilder builder)
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IdentityServiceCollectionUIExtensions.AddDefaultIdentity[TUser](IServiceCollection services, Action`1 configureOptions)
>   at WebApplication1.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in /tmp/8d75733ffb7bf8d/Startup.cs:line 33
>   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.InvokeCore(Object instance, IServiceCollection services)
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.g__Startup|0(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IServiceCollection services)
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.b__0(IServiceCollection services)
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.UseStartup(Type startupType, HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.b__0(HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
>   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
>   at WebApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in /tmp/8d75733ffb7bf8d/Program.cs:line 16
>   /opt/startup/startup.sh: line 11:    29 Aborted                 (core dumped) dotnet "WebApplication1.dll"

Comment: Last time I checked, the Linux based app services didn't yet support .Net Core 3. It should however work if you publish your app as self-contained.

Comment: The Linux based app service supports .Net core 3. You can see the error log `'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'` this binary is part of .Net core 3

Comment: I've just turned off self-contained builds in my build pipelines and can confirm that .Net Core 3 is now supported, so that's apparently not the issue. One more suggestion I have is try to delete all files before publishing or try to re-create the app service.

Comment: I did that and I even created a new project but this error comes again and again if I used the kudu. The same app pass the build if I used to build it using Microsoft (DevOps) in preview